# Homogenous second order differential equation that seems not to be solvable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the given equation:

$(x^2+y^2)dx+(x^2-xy)dy=0$

When I check for it to have a common partial derivative, I find that

$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=(x^2+y^2)_y=2y$

and the second

$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=(x^2-xy)_x=2x-y$

Thus, it does not seem to have common partial derivative. What can be done to solve it?

UPDATE:

by Moo's suggestion we get:

$(1+u^2)dx+(1-u)(xdu+udx)=0$

$(1+u^2)dx+(xdu+udx-uxdu-u^2dx)=0$

$(1+u)dx+x(1-u)du$

$\frac{1+u}{1-u}dx=-xdu$

this gives:

$lnx+c=-\int\frac{1}{1+u}+\frac{u}{1+u}du$

$lnx+c=-ln|1+u|+\int1du-\int\frac{1}{1+u}du$

$lnx+c=u-2ln|u+1|$

Insert for $u=y/x$

$lnx+c=-2ln|y/x+1|+y/x$

Rewriting this seems difficult, as I tried [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354875/rewrite-fracyx2-ln1-fracyx-lnx-lnc-without-logarithms/4354892#4354892).

Comment: can't say i worked...how do you mean?

Comment: I got this $y=xv$ and $y'v+xv'$ $\rightarrow$ $(x^2+v^2x^2)dx+(x^2-x^2v)dv=0. $ $\frac{\partial M}{\partial v}=2vx^2$ and $\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-2vx^2+2x$

Comment: And by inserting for $y=vx$ and $y'=v'x+v$, I get an even more complicated equation  $(x^2+v^2x^2)dx+x^3\frac{dv}{dx}+x^2v-x^3v\frac{dv}{dx}-x^2v^2=0$

Comment: See my answer on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354875/rewrite-fracyx2-ln1-fracyx-lnx-lnc-with-separated-variable/4354892#4354892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given

$$\tag 1 (x^2+y^2)dx+(x^2-xy)dy=0$$

It is not an [*Exact Equation*](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/exact.aspx), so we will try something else, rewriting $(1)$

$$\tag 2 (x^2+y^2)+(x^2-xy)y'=0$$

Let (example of this [*approach*](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/Homogeneous_x_and_y))

$$y = v x ~~~\mbox{so}~~~ y' = v + x v'$$

Substituting into $(2)$ and simplifying

$$x^2(x v' + v - x v' v + 1) = 0$$

Solving for $v'$

$$v' = \dfrac{v+ 1}{x(v -1)}$$

This is a [*Separable Equation*](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/separable.aspx) , so please continue.

Comment: Done! Thanks! See my last point in the update.

Comment: You are correct, I'd leave it in that form, else you'd e stuck with the Lambert-W Function.

Comment: Thanks Moo! My professor makes many mistakes actually...

Comment: I do tons of them myself, especially in Calculus, but I have never had a Professor who did.