# Rewrite $-\frac{y}{x}+2\ln|1+\frac{y}{x}|+\ln|x|=\ln|c|$ with separated variables and without logarithms

Tags: calculus

This seems simple maybe to some, but I can't get this right.

I have $-\dfrac{y}{x}+2\ln|1+\frac{y}{x}|+\ln|x|=\ln|c|$

And I  want to rewrite it nicely, with no logarithms and in the form $y=f(x)$

I tried and got

$y=x[\ln c+2\ln(1+y/x)+\ln x]$

alternatively:

$e^{-y/x}+(1+y/x)^2+x-c=0$

but then neither went any further.

Can't say I am able to separate the $x$ and $y$'s.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? Can you use $x = \ln a + \ln b = \ln (ab) \implies ab = e^x$? Can you split into cases to deal with absolute term?

Comment: Re-writing without logarithms is one thing; separating the $x$ and $y$'s is another. You can do the former without doing the latter ... which is good, because you can't do the latter at all.

Comment: That was my problem, I got $x[\ln c+2\ln(1+y/x)+\ln x]=y$ at best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$-\dfrac{y}{x}+2\ln|\frac{x+y}{x}|+\ln|x|=\ln|c|$$
Analytically solving this equation for $y$ cannot be done with a finite number of elementary functions. A special function is required, namely the LambertW function :
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html
$$-\dfrac{y}{x}+2\ln|\frac{x+y}{x}|-2\ln(2)+\ln|x|=\ln|c|-2\ln(2)$$
$$-\dfrac{y}{x}+2\ln|\frac{x+y}{2x}|=\ln|c|-2\ln(2)-\ln|x|$$
$$-\dfrac{y}{2x}+\ln|\frac{x+y}{2x}|=\frac12\ln|c|-\ln(2)-\frac12\ln|x|$$
$$\dfrac{x+y}{-2x}+\ln|\frac{x+y}{2x}|=\frac12\ln|c|-\ln(2)-\frac12\ln|x|-\frac12$$
$$\dfrac{x+y}{-2x}+\ln|\frac{x+y}{-2x}|=\frac12\ln|c|-\ln(2)-\frac12\ln|x|-\frac12$$
Let $X=\dfrac{x+y}{-2x}\quad;\quad \ln|C|=\frac12\ln|c|-\ln(2)-\frac12\quad$and$\quad \ln|Y|=\ln|C|-\frac12\ln|x| $
$$X+\ln|X|=\ln|Y|\quad\implies\quad Xe^X=Y$$
Which solution is
$$X=W(Y)$$
$$\dfrac{x+y}{-2x}=W\left(\frac{C}{\sqrt{|x|}} \right)$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=-x-2x\;W\left(\frac{C}{\sqrt{|x|}} \right)}$$
This is the closed form solution involving the Lambert W function.

$C$ is a constant related to $c$ with the relationship given above.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Explanation:

$-\frac{y}{x}+2\ln|1+\frac{y}{x}|+\ln|x|=\ln|c|$

Using the basic formulae of logarithm:

$\ln a + \ln b = \ln (ab)..(i) $

$\ln (a^x)=x\ln(|a|)...(ii)$

We get:

$\ln\left|(1+\frac{y}{x})^2\cdot\frac{x}{c}\right|=\frac{y}{x}$

Raising both LHS and RHS to the power of e we get :

$|(1+\frac{y}{x})^2\cdot\frac{x}{c}|=e^\frac{y}{x}$

$(x+y)^2=cx.e^\frac{y}{x}$

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is what I thought too, but my Professor got: $(x+y)^2=ce^{y/x}$

Comment: Your answer was flagged for being low-quality. Kindly consider elaborating more on the work that led to your conclusion.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thank you,I have elaborated my answer.

Comment: @ViolaPlayer In that case you must recheck if you have written down the correct question,being sure of which you may ask your Professor to clarify any further doubt that persists.

Comment: Thanks, +1 to your answer.